# Win8/Metro: Url and Document in WebView control?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, microsoft-metro, browser

I am creating a metro-style version for one of my apps, coded in c#. I need to access a web page, get the url and html code from that page and then use them.

In the winforms version, i used a WebBrowser control and its properties, .Url and .Document.ActiveElement.OuterHtml/InnerHtml.

For the metro-style app, i used a WebView control to access the page but it doesn't have such properties and i can't find anywhere how to get the url and the html code.

Anybody knows how to do that? Thanks in advance!

Edit: something like this (winforms, C#):

```
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted+=delegate
{
    if (webBrowser1.Url.ToString ().StartsWith ("http://www.google.com/"))
    {
        string url=webBrowser1.Url.ToString ();
        string htmlCode=webBrowser1.Document.ActiveElement.InnerHtml;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope that [this is the answer you need](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/embedding-a-web-browser-in-a-windows-8-metro-c-application.htm).

Comment: Not really. Sorry. I need to GET the url and the html code while the user is navigating (see the edit), not to SET the url or a html code.